# Need to associate unique integer value with classes

Tags: delphi, oop, inheritance

Alright, so I have a base class which we'll call `TFruit`. From this there are various descendants like `TApple`, `TOrange` and so on. I need to save the properties of the descendant classes to a file.

In order to be able to create the right class when loading the data, each class needs to have an `ID` that I write to the file before writing the actual data. Currently, I've come up with the following way of doing it:

```
type
  TFruit = class
    const ID = 0;
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
    const ID = 1;
  end;

  TOrange = class(TFruit)
    const ID = 2;
  end;
```

Testing this, I found out that I need to be super careful which class I declare. If I use this:

```
  var Fruit: TFruit;

  Fruit := TOrange.Create;
```

...then `Fruit.ID` will return **zero**. However, declaring `Fruit` as a `TOrange` will yield the expected result `Fruit.ID = 2` (anyone know why?)

So basically, am I doing this right or is there a better way to do it? Having to create a class function and return a value from there seems very ugly by comparison (extra function declaration, implementation and code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier to maintain solution would be to create a mapping class where you register all classes you'd like to convert to an integer.

**Advantages**

- Ability to detect duplicate registrations.
- Independent of your class structure.
- Includes the transformation back to a classname.

**Usage**

```
  RegisterClass.Register(0, TFruit);
  RegisterClass.Register(1, TApple);
  RegisterClass.Register(2, TOrange);
```

**Implementation**

```
  TRegisterClass = class
  private
    FList: TStringList;
  public
    function FindID(AClass: TClass): Integer;
    function FindClassName(const ID: Integer): string;
    procedure Register(const ID: Integer; AClass: TClass);
  end;
  ...
  function TRegisterClass.FindID(AClass: TClass): Integer;
  begin
    Assert(Assigned(AClass));

    Result := -1;
    if FList.IndexOf(AClass.ClassName) <> -1 then
      Result := Integer(FList.Objects[FList.IndexOf(AClass.ClassName)]);
  end;

  function TRegisterClass.FindClassName(const ID: Integer): string;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    Result := EmptyStr;
    for I := 0 to Pred(FList.Count) do
      if Integer(FList.Objects[I]) = ID then
      begin
        Result := FList[I];
        Exit;
      end;
  end;

  procedure TRegisterClass.Register(const ID: Integer; AClass: TClass);
  begin
    if IsAlreadyRegistered(ID) then 
      raise Exception.Create('Duplicate ID Registration')
    else if IsAlreadyRegistered(AClass) then 
      raise Exception.Create('Duplicate Class Registration');

    FList.AddObject(AClass.ClassName, Pointer(ID)); 
  end;
```

*Please note that there are better structures to map a String to an Integer. Writing this without a compiler and don't knowing many basic structures beyond Delphi5, I've chosen an obvious implementation.*

*Note that the IsAlreadyRegistered overloaded functions still have to be written*

Comment: For convenience one could add a class method to the base-class of registered objects returning the ID of that class. And since class methods(unlike C# style static methods) receive the class-type as `self` parameter this works as expected.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, true but that would require each class to "know" it's ID wich can be avoided and it could become a pain creating new descendants in trying to figure out what the next available ID is.

Comment: No I mean that this method calls your `FindID` function with `self` as param. But it might be architecturally better if classes themselves don't know about IDs since they can be considered an implementation detail of the serializer.

Answer (score 3):

there are many possibilities, for example:

```
function TFruit.GetClassId(): Word;
begin
  Result := CRC16(ClassName);
end;
```

Comment: Collision on such short strings? Near impossible.

Answer (score 2):

> anyone know why?

Because you're declaring a class field? TOrange inherits from TFruit, so it has the ID=0 field too. Then you override it with another ID=2 field. Now you have two of these. If you cast TOrange to TFruit then you're getting inherited field, this is precisely the way to access them.

If you're on Delphi 2010+, use attributes:

```
[ClassId(4)] TOrange = class(TFruit)
```

But why do you need these IDs in the first place? You'll have to manually mark your every class type, this is prone to errors. Just use class name.

```
var t: TOrange;
begin
  writeFile(t.Classname, t.Data);
```

If you're so concerned with space, keep a classname-id table at the beginning of the file and assign IDs dynamically as you go:

```
procedure WriteObject(c: TObject);
var id: integer;
begin
  if not GetAlreadyRegisteredClassnameId(c.Classname, id) then
    id := AddClassnameToTable(c.Classname);

  writeToCache(id, c.Data)
end;

procedure WriteFile()
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ObjectCount-1 do
    WriteObject(objects[i]);
  OutputClassnameTableToFile;
  OutputObjectCacheToFile;
end;
```

(Of course ignoring memory constraints here for demonstrative purposes, but it's easy to do this without memory cache too)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need

```
type
  TFruit = class
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
  end;

  TOrange = class(TFruit)
  end;
```

and then you can use `Fruit.ClassName` and `Fruit.ClassType`, can't you?

```
function ClassToID(const Fruit: TFruit): word;
begin
  if Fruit is TApple then
    result := 1
  else if Fruit is TOrange then
    result := 2;
end;
```

or

```
TFruitClass = class of TFruit;  

type
  TFruitAndID = record
    FruitClass: TFruitClass;
    ID: word;
  end;

const FruitIDs: array[0..1] of TFruitAndID =
  ((FruitClass: TApple; ID: 1), (FruitClass: TOrange; ID: 2));

function ClassToID(Fruit: TFruit): word;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(FruitIDs) do
    if FruitIDs[i].FruitClass = Fruit.ClassType then
      Exit(FruitIDs[i].ID);
end;
```

Comment: No. I need to save many hundred thousands of "fruits" to a file and for space reasons I do not want to use the class name. I need a number that I will write as a Word (16-bit) field in the file.

Comment: @David: You can write a `ClassToID` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Delphi 2010 you can use [attributes](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/delphi-attributes-understanding-using-attributes-in-delphi.htm) to tag your classes with the ID.

Comment: Sadly I'm using Delphi 2005 for this project. If it was D2010 I'd probably go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on other angle: why ID is not an read-only object property (instead of a class const)?

So:

```
 type
   TFruit = class
   protected
     FId: Integer;
   published
     property ID:Integer read FId;
   end;

   TApple = class(TFruit)
     constructor Create; 
   end;

   TOrange = class(TFruit)
     constructor Create; 
   end;

<...>
constructor TApple.Create;
begin
  FId := 1;
end;

constructor TOrange.Create;
begin
  FId := 2;
end;
```

So, your example code will work now. (The descendants can see FId because it's a protected field).
EDIT: changes the visibility from ***public*** to ***published***. But the same can be achieved using the $RTTI directive to allow RTTI to public members.

Comment: For RTTI to work, iirc the property needs to have `published` visibility (the example code in the question uses published implicitly)

Comment: @mjustin - this depends on the Delphi version 2010+ has extended RTTI

Comment: @Gerry: the code is required to work with Delphi 2005 (as I have seen in a comment), but you are right :)